# Why browsers don't just support require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify, require

Why doesn't browsers vendors introduce a support for `require API` as **node environments** do, why doesn't browsers vendors just integrate node environment in their browsers and make it easy for developers to use require API without the need to use tools like **webpack** or **browserify** and many configurations.

Are there any limitations, problems for implementing node environment in the browsers?

Comment: Counter questions - what would make it *desirable* for browser vendors to do ALL OF THAT. Remember, that's extra complexity they have to manage for their product. Why add it? What do they gain from it?

Comment: Also see [Eric Lippert's writeup on "Why doesn't C# implement top level methods"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods) - it's more widely applicable for any "Why X doesn't do Y".

Comment: Thanks for that link, but you asked me why add it??...they add a new capability for this product as any other capability and this will make the life easier, isn't  that a good reason??

Comment: It's not just "adding it". It also has to work with *everything else* in the browser. That's quite a big complexity to drop in an already quite complex project like a modern browser. And you claim it "adds new capability"...so? All software vendors are *constantly* working on new capabilities. Why is *this one* higher priority than anything else? Also, it's a false assumption that any extra stuff is good - if my browser starts reading and sorting my email for me, I wouldn't be happy. This new extra would certainly be controversial at least.

Answer (score 1):

> why doesn't browsers vendors introduce a support for require API

They have settled on the ES6 module standard instead (which Node.js also supports).

> why doesn't browsers vendors just integrate node environment in their browsers

Node.js does many things that are not desirable in a browser environment (like direct access to the file system and the ability to open raw network sockets). It would be a security nightmare.

Comment: So can i say that the biggest issue for this is the security part??